# Casting problem in C# generic method

Tags: c#, generics, collections, casting, methods

I'm having some trouble with a generic method I'm writing.  It has the following signature;

```
public static ThingCollection<T> GetThings<T>(...) where T : Thing
```

There are several classes; ThingA, ThingB and ThingC that inherit from Thing; and I want to be able to have code something like this in the method.

```
var things = new ThingCollection<T>();

if (typeof(T) == typeof(Thing))
  foreach (var item in someCollection)
    things.Add((T)new Thing(...));
else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ThingA))
  foreach (var item in someCollection)
    things.Add((T)new ThingA(...));
else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ThingB))
  foreach (var item in someCollection)
    things.Add((T)new ThingB(...));
else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ThingC))
  foreach (var item in someCollection)
    things.Add((T)new ThingC(...));
else
  throw new Exception("Cannot return things of type " + typeof(T).ToString());

return things;
```

The problem is that I get a *best overloaded method match has invalid arguments* error if I don't cast the new objects.  Adding the T casts as shown above is fine for the new Thing() but reports *Cannot convert type 'ThingA' to 'T'* for the other new calls.  Intellisense indicates that T is a Thing but I don't understand why I can't cast the other objects to Thing, as they inherit from it.

Perhaps this is not the right way to be doing what I'm trying to do.  Am I on the right track?  Perhaps missing some small nuance, or should I be doing something else entirely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't get what you are trying to do with that code.

If you want to create a Collection of Things where you could add any type of class derived from Thing, ThingCollection should not have a Typename: it's supposed  to be a collection for concrete types.

E.g, implementing A ThingCollection this way:

```
public class ThingCollection : List<Thing> {}
```

now you can do

```
ThingCollection tc = new ThingCollection();
tc.Add(new ThingA());
tc.Add(new ThingB());
tc.Add(new ThingC());
```

Assuming of course that ThingA, ThingB and ThingC inherits from Thing.

Or maybe you want to filter derived types of Things with the GetThings() i.e. you want that a call to  GetThings() returns a ThingCollection.

Comment: This was a big help. I was battling to get to grips with generics as I didn't realise I didn't need to make ThingCollection generic just because it inherits from a generic list.

Answer (score 3):

Primarly I think, this code snippet has bad design. If you add "ThingD" class, you need change in another part of code, for clear behaviour.
You should use something like:

```
public static ThingCollection<T> GetThings<T>(...) where T : Thing, new()
...
...
T item = new T();
item.Something = Whatever();
```

Or you can implement the "ICloneable" interface int Thing class.

Answer (score 3):

The code violates Liskov substitution principle, as it tries to test the type of T before using it.

To avoid this you could use dictionary/strategy combination or visitor pattern.

If T is ThingB the cast (T)ThingA is invalid, so the code is actually wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If they use a common interface (IThing) you should be able to cast to that.